# How do I show the probability of failure in my program? (using a lock-free stack)

Tags: probability

I've got a question about code I'm writing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831200/lock-free-stack-is-this-a-correct-usage-of-c11-relaxed-atomics-can-it-be-pr), and am looking for a way to see into the math of what's happening. Thought you guys could help :)

I'll see what I can do about describing the situation, as it's rather complex, and I'm not sure where to start with this on the numbers side. I'll start with what the code is.

What is a lock free stack?

A lock free stack is a container that can be used in computer programming which allows for the reading and writing of data from any thread without the use of locks. *(locks are the "traditional" solution to ensuring the program doesn't run into collision problems when accessing the same data from multiple threads.)*

The lock free way relies on a special compare_and_exchange instruction found in most modern processors.

What is does is this:

I pass two values to the compare_and_exchange, expected, and desired. If expected matches what's already there, then set the value to desired. If it doesn't, then the memory location that held "expected" will be updated to the new value of what was there.

Ok, great. So this means that I can read the value at the head of the queue, set my pointers properly, TRY to update the head element... and it'll only go through if I was right about the head element in the first place - thus ensuring I only update if there were no changes between the time I read the value in head, and the time that I went to update it.

There's a problem though. *(don't worry, I'm getting to the math part :) )* The problem is that I can read the head, get my pointers setup, run my compare_exchange, receive true and have everything go all wrong. It's a rare collision referred to as the "ABA" problem. Basically, the head pointer could be removed and put back before I get to updating it. And if that happens, my program will crash.

The solution that I'm using is to attach identification numbers to the pointers. That way, I'm looking to not only guarantee that the head pointer is of the same value, but that IS the same one. The identification must also match.

Here's the thing though. I only have a limited amount of space to store the identification numbers. How much space do I need to ensure that the chances of collision are so low that they are effectively zero?

The ABA collisions are quite rare. I'm going to guess something like 1 in 1,000,000 in a high-contention scenario. For there to be a collision with the "solution" involving identification numbers, not only does the ABA collision have to occur, but it must occur on the same identification number.

I expect that the increase of bits to the identification would decrease the chance of a collision exponentially, and for most/all use cases reduce it to a *true* zero as most use cases would not be sustain a high contention scenario long enough for this to ever happen.

So now, my question. How many bits of data do I truly need to ensure that a true collision will "never" occur. *("never" meaning so low as to be effectively zero)*

Comment: I recommend asking this question on the programmer and/or theoretical CS board as well.